# Probability distribution of time at which 2 random walks meet

Tags: probability-distributions, brownian-motion, random-walk

For a research project I was given a result, which describes the **time distribution for the meeting time of two superdiffusive random walks** (superdiffusive random walks don't have a standard deviation $\sim \sqrt{t}$, but rather of a higher power, in this case we have the standard deviation $\sim t^{2/3}$).

Specifically, we have **two random walks, which start at the same time, but with a certain distance $l$ apart**. The distribution which I was given now describes the probability distribution for the time at which the two walks will meet as:
$$
\hat p(t,l) = \frac{\pi l}{\sqrt{2\cdot5 t^{4/3}}}\exp{\frac{-\pi l^2}{2\cdot5t^{4/3}}}
$$

I am struggling with deriving/understanding this result. I have done some digging and found out that the probability for such a **random walk beeing located at spacial coordinate $x$ at time $t$ is given by**
$$
p(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi D t^{4/3}}}\exp{\frac{-x^2}{4Dt^{4/3}}}
$$
where $D\in \mathbb R$ is some constant, which will shift the value of the standard deviation.

I think the upper result should be derivable from the lower one somehow, but I can't figure out how. Maybe someone has some ideas or tipps for a derivation. Thank you very much in advance!